# Prometheus: What's the best way to alert on a condition?

Tags: java, prometheus

I'm using Prometheus to collect metrics for a java application.  In my application, I'm making calls to authenticate via an API.  I'm devising the best approach for Prometheus to send an alert to my e-mail if authentication to the API ever fails. I'm thinking of using a gauge, initializing it as 0, and if authentication ever fails, increase the gauge value to 1 -- which will then fire off an alert that monitors the value of the gauge (if gauge > 0, fire an alert).

Once authentication succeeds, I'll revert the value of the gauge back to 0.

Is this typically how custom alerts are created in Prometheus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the best approach. One extreme situation is let's say you have 100 authentications per minute, with 99 of them failing and Prometheus scraping once a minute, immediately after the one successful authentication. You'd have 99% failure rate and never find out about it.

If on the other hand you increment a counter for every authentication failure, you can take a `rate()` over the past few minutes (to work around any failed/delayed scrapes) and will definitely know whether there were any authentication failures during the past few minutes.

As for the alert, you can set it up to fire whenever that rate goes above 0 (probably not ideal, as there will always be the random failure) or over some non-zero threshold. Plus, optionally add conditions on the number of total authentication requests (100% of one request is different from 50% of 1000 requests) and/or the duration for which the condition has to hold (i.e. there may be one API user that uses the wrong credentials and all their requests fail, but all over a few seconds vs. one authentication failing every few seconds). You'll have to figure out for yourself what works in your particular situation.